# Is there any existing algorithm or formula that can calculate the complexity of a dataset?

Tags: data-mining, dataset

Suppose that we have a dataset of n elements each element is composed of m sub elements, is there any existing algorithm that we can use to calculate the complexity of this dataset?

I mean by the complexity anything that includes the following elements:

- Diversity of dataset (number of distinct elements)
- Distance between each element
- Correlation between the elements of this dataset
- Size of the dataset

Comment: You can determine these things fairly easily in your database, and efficiently so if you accept approximations (e.g.,. APPROX COUNT DISTINCT). You can also define a figure that combines multiple metrics, but how is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

well ... *"if n elements each element is composed of m sub elements"* sound like you have a set of sets from discrete objects. If this is the case you can go through Combinatorial Analysis like Graph Theory. You can model it in two ways:

1) **Using [Hypergraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph)**: You have your elements as hyper-edges of a Hypergraph. This model lets you compute distances, diversities, sizes, and many more graph theoretical measures e.g. look at [this](http://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1000385), [this](http://toilers.mines.edu/RMCWiC/2014/sites/default/files/posters/csuconf-final20.pdf) and [this](http://www.math.iisc.ernet.in/~ifcam/new_avenue/Slides/Seminars/Ravindran.pdf).

2) **Simple [Graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics))**: You can create simple complete graphs from each sub-element and connect them to other [complete graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) (forming [cliques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory))) of other sub-elements. See the example bellow:

```
element1 = [[a,b,c],[b,c,d],[e,f,g]]  
Graph = [(a,b),(b,c),(a,c),(b,c),(c,d),(b,d),(e,f),(e,g),(f,g)]
```

using this you will have a huge graph (network) of your object on which you can calculate [tones of structural and statistical measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_science).

I assume my thought were naive as your question is not clear and you need to provide more detailed example to get a more accurate answer.

Good Luck!